# Logstash does not start main pipeline and produces no output on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I have installed Logstash and Elasticsearch on an Ubuntu 16.04 machine with 4 gb ram using `apt-get install logstash`.

When I boot the service with `systemctl start logstash` it does start the process (I can see it using `ps aux | grep logstash`) but no index is created in Elasticsearch. I thought I would try to debug it by just running the process in the terminal but when I do it creates no output.

This is the command I run:

```
sudo -u logstash /usr/share/logstash/bin/logstash \
 --path.settings /etc/logstash \
 -f /etc/logstash/conf.d/std.conf \
 --config.test_and_exit \
 --log.level debug
```

Nothing ever happens - it produces no output. It does not tell me that the main pipeline has started or gives me an error or anything.

I have checked `/var/log/logstash` put the folder is empty. I have checked `syslog` but there are only a few entries from when it was running as a service (only entries like `Mar 22 20:11:21 elasticsearch-logstash systemd[1]: Started logstash.`)

I installed logstash as root and I have tried `chown -R logstash:adm` both `/usr/share/logstash/`, `var/log/logstash` and `/etc/logstash` but nothing works.

I only have a single configuration file `/etc/logstash/conf.d/main.conf` and I have tried several pipeline configurations but same result:

**main.conf (version 1)**

```
input { 
  stdin {

  } 
} 
output {
  stdout {

  } 
}
```

**main.conf (version 2)**

```
input {
  stdin {
  }
}
output {
 file {
   path => "/var/log/logstash/yo.log"
 }
}
```

**main.conf (version 3)**

```
input { 
  stdin {

  } 
} 
output {
  stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

None of these configurations change the outcome in anyway. I have no idea why it is silently failing on me.

It should be noted that I have also tried installing by downloading the tar file and running Logstash from the downloaded directory with same result.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was the lack of entropy problem.

The issue: https://github.com/elastic/logstash/issues/5491

The solution: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-setup-additional-entropy-for-cloud-servers-using-haveged